# How to fix NoSuchElementException Scanner?

Tags: java, android-studio

So `Scanner` is throwing `NoSuchElementException` No line found, its like, its not waiting for my input, note that I only call `nextLine()` I don't call `nextInt()` nowhere. I just call `nextLine()` and only once.

This **all** my code

```
public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at com.ekisache.games.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:9)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Test:MyClass.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Its pretty weird as in my other computer this works, and in this one it doesn't

Working code in my mac:

[image]

In my windows PC:

[image]

Comment: In which context is that code being executed? From the console? From an IDE?

Comment: @Themelis from IDE, android studio

Comment: Look the `System.in` corresponds to the *Standard Input* which is usually the input from the keyboard (and `System.out` is usually the console) but maybe Android Studio is changing this. Is the same code which works on your other computer run from Android Studio as well?

Comment: The code is fine, I mean there can't be a mistake from you're side with this -> 

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());`

Comment: @Themelis Yes, same code, same IDE

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29314006/9164071

Comment: But I don't have anyhing connected to this computer, just the mouse. Btw I tried with intellij and it works too, the problem its only in Android Studio. Is there a specific settings I should check?

Comment: May I ask why you need to take input from keyboard in Android?

Comment: Its not an android app, well the android app its in another module, this module is "plain java" and I'm trying to create a console tool in which I need to get the input

Comment: So it will be convenient to have both modules in the same project the tool and the app, I've done this a lot of times before, just not in this computer.

Comment: You've done it also a lot of times before using android studio?

Comment: Yep, I have a bunch of projects like this, and in my other computer it works(My other computer is a mac btw) don't know if its relevant but just in case

Comment: I believe you should try to execute the same code through the android studio in your mac, just to see.

Comment: I did, I'll edit the the answer with some pictures...

Comment: @Themelis I added screen shots

Comment: @NoelDiaz - This problem should go away after restarting Android Studio.

Comment: I've done that too, restarted android studio, restarted PC, cleaned projects

Comment: Have you found any solutions to that?

Answer (score -1):

Try assigning to a variable first,

```
String yourInput = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.printLn(yourInput)
```